# defining structure in return type of a function

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s
{
    int data;
} fun()
{
    static struct s ss; 
    ss.data = 20;
    return ss;
}

int main()
{
    struct s ss;
    memcpy(&ss, &(fun()), sizeof(struct s));

    printf("\n Data: :%d", ss.data);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, Im trying to define a struct where the return type is mentioned. `struct s` is defined successfully.

Is this a valid usage? I never seen real scenario like this.

How to make this program to work??

I'm getting this compiler error:

```
asd.c: In function ‘main’:
asd.c:21:15: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything apart from your `memcpy` line is correct (albeit a bit hard to read), and the compiler error tells you what's wrong: You can't take the address of a "temporary" (i.e. of the result of a function call ex­pres­sion).

You could and should however just write the much more natural way:

```
struct s ss = fun();
```

Comment: `error: new types may not be defined in a return type` - gcc 4.6.1

Comment: doh sorry. I compiled with g++. sorry all is fine

Comment: Notice in here, fun returns a copy of ss. So changes to ss in main, will not propagated to ss in fun.

Comment: Just for the vocabulary, temporary is not describing things correctly. This is usually called an "rvalue", and you are correct that the address can't be taken of such a beast. There are other "temporaries" in C called compound literals who's address can be taken.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Where in the C standard does it say that compound literals are temporary? Anonymous, yes, but temporary? Moreover, where in the C standard is defined the concept of an "rvalue"?

Comment: Where does it ever speak of a temporary? The standard says: "What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
as the ‘‘value of an expression’’."